# How do I prevent applications from starting with their windows maximized?

Tags: x11, window-management, window

Some applications seem to be written the way they start maximized by default. I don't want this to happen ever. Is there a way to force disable this? There is a program called `maximus` that maximizes (and undecorates) applications automatically as they start - is there an program that does just the opposite (not minimizes but normalizes though) perhaps?

Comment: Can you give examples of applications? Some methods may only work if the application is sufficently well-behaved. What window manager are you using? Both the application and the window manager can set the window size (and any other program that has a connection to the X display, but only the application and the window manager are supposed to do it).

Comment: @Gilles One example is LibreOffice - its individual components like LibreOffice Calc or Writer start mazimized by default but they remember the window position and size once resized and closed so they won't start mazimized the next time. Another application is Ristretto - the default picture viewer in XFCE, I have posted a separate question about it earlier: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250829/how-to-disable-ristretto-from-starting-maximized-whenever-i-couble-click-a-pictu

Answer (score 3):

You have few options:

- if this is possible configure application itself via config file or some clickable menu.
- certain applications support geometry changing from `.Xresources` (or `.Xdefaults`) file.
- If neither of the above is possible then you need to use external tool to change window properties. One of the better choice can be `wmctrl` software - you can toggle fullscreen mode with it (see `-b` option in `man wmctrl`) or set precisely window geometry according to your needs, e.g.

  ```
  wmctrl -i -r 0x01 -e 0,10,20,300,400
  ```

  will place window number `0x01` to position `10,20` (x,y of top left corner), `300` width and `400` height. The window number you may find with `wmctrl -l`. All of that can be put into the shell function so that when you run certain program it will start in fullscreen mode (as designed), but immediately will resize to given geometry as desired.